# What does the double colon before println mean in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

What does the double colon before `println` mean in the Kotlin code below?

```
class InitOrderDemo(name: String) {
   val firstProperty = "First property: $name".also(::println)
}
```

The code prints:

> First property: hello

Comment: [`.also`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/also.html) takes a block `(T) -> Unit`, `::` is passing a reference to `println` as a callable rather than writing out e.g. a lambda `{ println(it) }`.

Comment: It's a [Callable reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#callable-references).

Answer (score 13):

From [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html#operators-and-special-symbols) `::` means:

> creates a member reference or a class reference.

In your example it's about **member reference**, so you can pass a function as a parameter to another function (aka [First-class function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function)).

As shown in the output you can see that `also` invoked `println` with the string value, so the `also` function may check for some condition or doing some computation before calling `println`.
You can rewrite your example using [lambda expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-functions) (*you will get the same output*):

```
class InitOrderDemo(name: String) {
   val firstProperty = "First property: $name".also{value -> println(value)}
}
```

You can also write your own function to accept another function as an argument:

```
class InitOrderDemo(name: String) {
    val firstProperty = "First property: $name".also(::println)
    fun andAlso (block : (String) -> Int): Int{
        return block(firstProperty)
    }
}

fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    InitOrderDemo("hello").andAlso(String::length).also(::println) 
}
```

Will print:

> First property: hello
>
> 21