# Why can I use Observer(adapter::submitList) instead of Observer { adapter.submitList(it) in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

The Code A is easy to understand.

But many pesons use `viewModel.allCheeses.observe(this, Observer(adapter::submitList))` instead of `viewModel.allCheeses.observe(this, Observer { adapter.submitList(it) })`.

In my mind the symbol *::*  indicate that it's class in Kotlin.

**Code A**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val adapter = CheeseAdapter()
        cheeseList.adapter = adapter

        viewModel.allCheeses.observe(this, Observer { adapter.submitList(it) })
        //viewModel.allCheeses.observe(this, Observer(adapter::submitList))


        initAddButtonListener()
        initSwipeToDelete()
}



public interface Observer<T> {
    /**
     * Called when the data is changed.
     * @param t  The new data
     */
    void onChanged(T t);
}
```

Comment: [What does the double colon before println mean in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51804120/3290339) and [Operators and Special Symbols of Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html#operators-and-special-symbols).

Comment: @Onik The first link doesn't cover this use of `::`; the second does, but to find where you probably already need to know about about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular use is a [bound method reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#bound-function-and-property-references-since-11):

> You can refer to an instance method of a particular object:
>
> ```
> val numberRegex = "\\d+".toRegex()
> println(numberRegex.matches("29"))
>
> val isNumber = numberRegex::matches
> println(isNumber("29"))
> ```
>
> Instead of calling the method matches directly we are storing a reference to it. Such reference is bound to its receiver. It can be called directly (like in the example above) or used whenever an expression of function type is expected:
>
> ```
> val numberRegex = "\\d+".toRegex()
> val strings = listOf("abc", "124", "a70")
> println(strings.filter(numberRegex::matches))
> ```
>
> Compare the types of bound and the corresponding unbound references. Bound callable reference has its receiver "attached" to it, so the type of the receiver is no longer a parameter:
>
> ```
> val isNumber: (CharSequence) -> Boolean = numberRegex::matches
> val matches: (Regex, CharSequence) -> Boolean = Regex::matches
> ```